# Powershell - Load XML file in Uppercase

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the below sample XML File, the others are larger.
When using XPATH filters to obtain the DataBaseServer Name for a specified Database Name i am using an XPATH command / filter to obtain this.
The same is also used to obtain other attributes from the XML.

Using XPATH is case sensitive.  The XML will sometimes be updated by an individual, so there may be some case inaccuracies within the XML.

When importing the XML into a Powershell variable, is there a way to import it so that it is imported in UPPERCASE every time?
I can then code the XPATHS to use UPPERCASE always.

Converting the XML files prior is not an option, as they are multiple xml files for different clients and are all version controlled.

```
<Orchestration>
  <Client Code="A_DEMO">
    <Environment Name="DEMO">
      <DataBaseServer Name="SERVER1" TYPE="SQL">
        <Database Name="LMS" />
      </DataBaseServer>
    </Environment>
  </Client>
</Orchestration>
```

I have tried the following:

```
[XML]$TextFile = (Get-Content -Path $ConfigFile).ToUpper()
```

This fails:

```
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument".
Error: "'XML' is an invalid name for processing instructions.
```

Am i missing something simple, or is this just not possible?

Comment: Your attempt does not work because it also upper-cases the XML declaration into something like `<?XML VERSION="1.0" ENCODING="UTF-8"?>`, which is illegal in XML and results in the `"'XML' is an invalid name for processing instructions.` error.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to retrieve an attribute without having to worry about case-sensitiveness, you could also use the `.` property method:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $ConfigFile -Raw
# I'm using all lowercase here to show this works uppercase or not
($xml.orchestration.client.environment.databaseserver | Where-Object {$_.database.name -eq 'lms' }).name
```

Result:

> SERVER1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load all values into an object as uppercase, you can do the following:

```
$str = Get-Content $ConfigFile -Raw
$regex = '(?<==\s*").*?(?=")'
$TextFile = [xml]([regex]::Replace($str,$regex,{ param($value) $value.Value.ToUpper() }))
```

The code relies on regex to match all values after `="` and before the next `"`. Those returned characters are forced into uppercase. `$value` as a parameter represents each `Match` object. The `Value` property contains the actual matched text.

---

Nobody will ever actually approve of this method as opposed to an XML parser. However, if you understand your data and where this could possibly fail, this method may work for you.